# Is there a Ganache-like in Cardano?

Tags: blockchain, developers

Currently, I have been playing around with the Cardano Playground and I was wondering if there is an existing tool already present where I can personally run a Cardano blockchain like Ganache of Ethereum blockchain?

Regards,

Ivan

Comment: Plutus playground simulates the working of a blockchain. Testnet with smart contract feature is expected before end May

Answer (score 3):

Yes?

In the [lecture #4](https://youtu.be/6Reuh0xZDjY) of the current Plutus Pioneer program, there's a way to run a faux blockchain with Plutus contracts.  The first 90 minutes are a Haskell tutorial, but then it goes into how to use the EmulatorTrace.

It's not a full testnet, so it might not be a full replacement for Ganache (which I haven't used), so maybe No.